# Vanilla JS Multi level navigation is not working in sublevels

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a very basic HTML multi navigation and it is working from first level. But it is not working on second level menu. For example. In my menu "About" page has submenu and inside of About menu "Profile" menu has another submenus. But when i click on "Profile" menu, it is not working. Can anyone help me to fix this. Thanks in Advance!

```js
let menus = document.querySelectorAll(".main-navigation ul li a");
menus.forEach((item)=>{
if(item.parentElement.querySelector("ul")) {
item.parentElement.classList.add("has-submenu");
}
});



let submenu = document.querySelectorAll(".has-submenu");
submenu.forEach((item)=>{
item.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
e.preventDefault();
let ul = e.target.parentElement.querySelector("ul");
let cs = window.getComputedStyle(ul).display;
if(cs==="block") {
ul.style.cssText="display:none";
}
else {
ul.style.cssText="display:block";
}

});

});
```

```css
.main-navigation ul {list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;font-family:arial;}
    .main-navigation ul li {padding:.35rem;background:#f9f9f9;}
    .main-navigation ul li ul {padding-left:1rem;display:none;}
    .main-navigation ul li a {display:block;text-decoration:none;}
```

```html
<div class="main-navigation">
<ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About +</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Profile +</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="">History</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Management</a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Vision</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Mission</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Services +</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Web Design</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Web Development</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
</ul>   
</div>
```

Comment: you need to add `.stopPropagation()` to you event handler. Your event is bubbling to the parent and immediately closing the sub.

Comment: why do you hate indents? very hard to read.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Casbum, Thank You for sharing knowledge on resolving issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is everything works on your code. But when clicking on a `.has-submenu` that is itself inside a `.has-submenu` the event listener is triggered for each element. I've added a topPropagation for the event to not bubble up, this will effectively prevent triggering on the parent `.has-submenu`.

```js
let menus = document.querySelectorAll(".main-navigation ul li a");
menus.forEach((item)=>{
if(item.parentElement.querySelector("ul")) {
item.parentElement.classList.add("has-submenu");
}
});



let submenu = document.querySelectorAll(".has-submenu");
submenu.forEach((item)=>{
item.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
e.preventDefault();
e.stopImmediatePropagation(); // HERE
let ul = e.target.parentElement.querySelector("ul");
console.log(ul);
let cs = window.getComputedStyle(ul).display;
if(cs==="block") {
ul.style.cssText="display:none";
}
else {
ul.style.cssText="display:block";
}

});

});
```

```css
.main-navigation ul {list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;font-family:arial;}
    .main-navigation ul li {padding:.35rem;background:#f9f9f9;}
    .main-navigation ul li ul {padding-left:1rem;display:none;}
    .main-navigation ul li a {display:block;text-decoration:none;}
```

```html
<div class="main-navigation">
<ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About +</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Profile +</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="">History</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Management</a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Vision</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Mission</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Services +</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Web Design</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Web Development</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
</ul>   
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Salketer, Many Thanks for your Help and Giving me an additional knowledge on Event Handler. Thank You!!!

Comment: Hi Salketer Can you also help me to collapse a sublevel menu when other sublevel menu is opened.

Comment: You simply need to get all the sibblings and set the correct cssStyle. The best would be to instead of using the cssText property, you'd use a class like "is-open" that way you could find all is-open ul and close them...

Comment: Thank You Salketer for your advice and giving me a thread. Actually, You doing a great Job which will make your life more better. Because recently, i had a question regarding OOP. But due to some discourage fellows in the stackoverflow, I did'nt get a positive answer and my permission for asking questions may be stoped. But your solution given me a chance to increase reputation. Thank You!!!